# The layer does not destruct when the Scene is replaced

Tags: cocos2d-x

Anybody has the same problem? I've add the layer to the scene. But when the scene exited and called its destruct method, the layer's destruct method was not called. Here is the code:

```
void TowerScene :: init()
{

    addchild(Tower::create());
    retrun true;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If I am not mistaken `cocos2dx` uses object pool which autoreleases objects (i.e. something like garbage collection).

Comment: Make sure you didn't retained `Tower` layer somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Thank you for response.I've checked it,and find no retain there.Actually ,the tower is my main layer.My game logic is all in it.I've used levelhelper and box2d in my game.Maybe it's about this.I will check it again.Thank you anyway.You are the first person answering me,a rookie in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CCTouchDispatcher`, `CCKeyboardDispatcher`, `CCScheduler` or other singletons use `retain` on delegate object when it's added, so, reference counter remains incremented until delegate removed. If you manually add the layer as delegate to scheduler or other, you must manually remove (unshedule) delegate inside `onExit` method.

To find problem you also can override `virtual void retain()` public method and set breakpoint in it. Backtrace will show, where reference counter was incremented.

P.S. Be sure, that super-methods of `init`, `onEnter`, `onExit` and other overrided methods are called. C++ way: `SuperClass::method()`

Comment: Thk U so much.What you said is right.When I call unscheduleAllselectors () methods in onExit() method.The reference does decrease.But there is a another factor contributing to the increasing referencecount of The tower layer.It's just about this method:tem_monster->die_action =CCSequence::create (XX,CCCallFuncN::actionWithTarget(this, callfuncN_selector(Tower ::dieCallBack)),NULL);Tem_monster is another object and it doesn't inherit any classes.tem_monster in some sense calling the dieCallBack methods which is defined in the Tower layer may work on the reference of the tower.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English.Hope you understand it. Your answer is big help to me.Thank you so much.

Comment: BTW,the retain method in CCObject Class is not virtual in my cocos2d-x.